# Select previous 12 months by month and year input

Tags: mysql

I am stuck trying to return the totals for the last 12 months when month and year are used as inputs.

I can get a whole year (from January to December) based on an input, but what I am after is say if i input ('08','2017') it will calculate totals for 08/2016-08/2017.

I know i will have to add in another input and assign it a value e.g `IN targetMonth int`, but I am unsure of how to go about the INTERVAL.

The 'date_admitted' column has values in the form of '2010-01-30'. Essentially the resulting table will look like:

```
Month    Total  %
08 2016   10    16
09 2016   10    16
10 2016   10    16
11 2016   10    16
12 2016   10    16
01 2017   10    16
  etc    etc   etc
```

heres my code for calcuating a whole year

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS YrReport;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE YrReport( 
IN targetYear int)
BEGIN
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_admitted, '%m') 
AS Month,
COUNT(id) 
AS Total,
ROUND(COUNT(id) / (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM 
accessions  
WHERE year(date_admitted) = targetYear)*100)
AS '%'
FROM accessions 
WHERE year(date_admitted) = targetYear
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_admitted, '%Y%m');
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: is the way to go adding an INTERVAL statement into the WHERE clause? i had a go at it but im thinking it wouldnt work because my inputs are int not DATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look into the whole code you wrote, but it seems that you can solve your problem by changing your `WHERE` conditions. Let us suppose you have a second parameter to your stored procedure,

```
....
IN targetMonth int)
```

then you could replace

```
WHERE year(date_admitted) = targetYear
```

by

```
WHERE ((YEAR(date_admitted) = targetYear) AND
       (MONTH(date_admitted) < targetMonth)) OR
      ((YEAR(date_admitted) = (targetYear - 1)) AND
       (MONTH(date_admitted) >= targetMonth))
```

and change the other `WHERE` condition in a similar way if necessary.

Coming back to your example, this would select `08/2016` (included) to `07/2017` (included) which is 12 months. If you want it to select `09/2016` to `08/2017` instead, you can adapt the code.

I think this will run quite fast compared to other solutions, but it will work only if you want to include exactly one year. You cannot easily adapt that code to include 13 months, for example.

Comment: @Downvoter Could you please elaborate what's wrong with that answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

If you have a numeric year, for example `2016`, you can use an expression like this to retrieve all rows with `date_admitted` in that calendaryear.

```
WHERE date_admitted >= MAKEDATE(year, 1)
  AND date_admitted <  MAKEDATE(year, 1) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

If you have some datestamp for a day, and you want to retrieve the twelve full months of data preceding that day (not year-to-date), do this.

```
WHERE date_admitted >= LAST_DAY(datestamp) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH
  AND date_admitted <  LAST_DAY(datestamp) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

This can be especially useful for the current date.

```
WHERE date_admitted >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH
  AND date_admitted <  LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If you need to group by month do something like this

```
 SELECT SUM(something), COUNT(*), LAST_DAY(date_admitted) month_ending
   FROM someTable
  GROUP BY LAST_DAY(date_admitted)
```

The use of [MySQL date arithmetic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) can get a little verbose. But it allows you to do lots of date filtering and grouping with precision.

One idiom is this.  The first day of the month containing a datestamp is

```
LAST_DAY(datestamp) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```